# Starting java desktop app from headless mode

Tags: java, process, awt, headless

I have created a java process that runs headless in the background that monitors mac machines. Part of the monitoring includes taking screenshots of the user's action and occasionally bringing up a chat window.
I am under the assumption that none of these actions can be performed from headless mode, please correct me if I am wrong. Is it possible to start another process from my headless mode process that is able to open the chat window or take the screenshots? How do I start such process from the headless process?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:  It is running on a mac so there is definitely a monitor, a mouse, and a keyboard, and we know for a fact somebody is sitting on it and using it.

Edit: It gets started through a daemon running on the machine.

Comment: Headless mode typically means that their is no keyboard, mouse or video support

Comment: But it is running on a mac so there is definitely a monitor, a mouse, and a keyboard, and we know for a fact somebody is sitting on it and using it.

Comment: Have you tried taking a snapshot? Or opening a chat window?

Comment: Yes, I get a headless exception. Unless i run the process from the console as the user. But that is not an option.

Comment: How are you starting it?

Comment: It gets started through a daemon running on the machine.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html), you might want to do some more investigation into "Agents"

Comment: headless means no GUI support, so no windows can be opened

Comment: This link says you can still do few things http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the link, that looks promising.

Comment: Neat way of doing it in my answer, in case anyone is interedted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30674344/1922771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following code in this [link](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=14380#responseChild87911) trying to run a command as the user that is signed into the machine:

```
loggedInUser=`/bin/ls -l /dev/console | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $3 }'`
declare -x LoginWindowPID="$(/bin/ps -axww | /usr/bin/grep loginwindo[w] | /usr/bin/awk '/console/{print $1;exit}')"
/bin/launchctl bsexec "${LoginWindowPID:?}" /usr/bin/sudo -u "$loggedInUser" COMMAND GOES HERE
```

Using that we can start the java process (or any headless process) with the following command in order for it to have access to the UI:

```
launchctl bsexec $(/bin/ps -axww | /usr/bin/grep loginwindo[w] | /usr/bin/awk '/console/{print $1;exit}') COMMAND GOES HERE
```